# Can't find file 'whichopensslcnf' while it's there in OpenVPN

Tags: server, vpn, file

I got a weird problem while trying to follow the tutorial *[How to set up a Raspberry Pi VPN server](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=81657)* for setting up [OpenVPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN) on a Raspberry Pi:

At 3.

```
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
. ./vars
./clean-all
./build-ca
```

My console for some reason ends up with an error:

```
root@Pi-VPN:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa#     cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
root@Pi-VPN:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa#     . ./vars
bash: ”/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa”/whichopensslcnf: No such file or directory
NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on ”/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa”/keys
root@Pi-VPN:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa#     ./clean-all
mkdir: cannot create directory `”/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa”/keys': No such file or directory
root@Pi-VPN:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa#     ./build-ca
./build-ca: 8: ./build-ca: ”/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa”/pkitool: not found
```

Why is it ending up with this error? My `whichopensslcnf` file is there for sure (I checked it with FTP). So that could not be the problem. Why isn't it finding this file then?

I just can't figure out what's wrong and nothing can be found about this problem on the Internet.

The output of Steve Robillard♦ question:

```
pi@Pi-VPN ~ $ ls -la /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
total 144
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 14 13:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 14 13:00 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   119 Feb 14 13:00 build-ca
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   352 Feb 14 13:00 build-dh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   188 Feb 14 13:00 build-inter
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   163 Feb 14 13:00 build-key
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   157 Feb 14 13:00 build-key-pass
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   249 Feb 14 13:00 build-key-pkcs12
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   268 Feb 14 13:00 build-key-server
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   213 Feb 14 13:00 build-req
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   158 Feb 14 13:00 build-req-pass
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   428 Feb 14 13:00 clean-all
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1457 Feb 14 13:00 inherit-inter
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   295 Feb 14 13:00 list-crl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   413 Feb 14 13:00 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7768 Feb 14 13:00 openssl-0.9.6.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8325 Feb 14 13:00 openssl-0.9.8.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8222 Feb 14 13:00 openssl-1.0.0.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8224 Feb 14 13:00 openssl-1.0.0.cnf-old-copy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12675 Feb 14 13:00 pkitool
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3757 Feb 14 13:00 README.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   918 Feb 14 13:00 revoke-full
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   178 Feb 14 13:00 sign-req
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Feb 14 13:00 tmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1861 Feb 14 13:03 vars
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   714 Feb 14 13:00 whichopensslcnf
pi@Pi-VPN ~ $ total 144
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the content of /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars and the output of ls -la /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/

Comment: @SteveRobillard I edited my question.

Comment: I still need to see the contents of the vars file.

Comment: Make sure you wrote "etc", not "ect" in the vars file

Answer (score 2):

On step 2 of the same tutorial:

```
export EASY_RSA=”/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa”
```

Make sure you didn't copy-pasted with the ”” but with "" like:

```
export EASY_RSA="/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa"
```